# Render is triggered by neither setState() nor forceUpdate()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple React setup which looks kind of like this:

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            flag: false
        };
    }

    update = () => {
        // changing DOM to test if re-render occurs
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '';

        this.setState({
            flag: true
        });

        this.forceUpdate();
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <table id="test">
                <tbody>
                <tr key="new">
                    <td>Row foo</td>
                    <td>Row bar</td>
                    <td>{this.state.flag ? 'Row foobar' : 'Row barfoo'}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}
```

When `this.update` is called the state is updated but the DOM does NOT re-render even with the `this.forceUpdate()` in place. Why does react ignore a state-change and the forceUpdate which should both trigger a re-render?

I also added a the test of clearing all content before the expected re-render and the content gets removed but stay removed as no re-render occurs.

**EDIT:** I removed all Redux-related code as the issue persists if I take Redux out of the mix. Here is a minimal CodeSandox as my actual code is ~ 3.5k LOC:

[image: Edit tabs-parent-pass-state]

Comment: @SultanH. Could you provide an answer with a short example? I would be grateful

Comment: Could you please show us your `render()` method in `App.js` ?

Comment: React recommends against direct DOM manipulation, it happens outside react's virtual DOM so it won't handle it like you're trying.  Also, almost 10/10 times if you are calling `forceUpdate` then you are "reacting" wrong and is usually an indication you have a logic error in a lifecycle function.  Also, you can attach handlers directly to a button via an `onClick` prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your attempt, I can say that you have **NOT** understood the [react lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) correctly.

**Let just consider your case,**

You rendered a component, text gets displayed on webpage, then you are clicking on button and changed rendered text also executing `setState`. And now you want the intial rendered text back on re-render.

**Now let me correct you here,**

Before first `setState` executes, your component goes through some life cycle methods and component `mounts`. When `setState` executes your component goes through another set of life cycle methods. These two phases are completly different.

The state of the component is maintained by `React`. So whatever changes you do in this phase will persist till the component unmounts.

To see the initial data you must reload the browser or must have some sort of navigation.

Comment: button with event-listener

Comment: `document.getElementById("test").textContent` this will make changes to DOM directly and react is not involved in this case.

Comment: I understand - how can I achieve an actual re-render as if the page is loading for the first time?

Comment: `componentWillMount` is the method which executes before your component mounts. In that method you can have some pre rendering logic.

Comment: Your layout should always represent the current state. So if you want to achieve re-render as if the page is loading for the first time you need to reset your state to the initial state.